# XAMPP and MySQL error on startup

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am getting this error when I try starting the MySQL service through the XAMPP control panel:

```
2014-08-17 14:53:44 6028 [ERROR] TCP/IP, --shared-memory, or --named-pipe should be configured on NT OS
2014-08-17 14:53:44 6028 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Anyone ran into this issue before and have a configuration change that may be used to get it running?

For reference, these are the settings within my.ini:

```
[client] 
port            = 3306
socket          = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "G:/Dev/xampp/tmp" 
datadir = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
# SECURITY CHANGES
skip-networking
local-infile=0

plugin_dir = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

skip-federated

server-id   = 1

innodb_data_home_dir = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "G:/Dev/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 32M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
innodb_flush_method = normal

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either enable named pipes by removing the comment before the option `enable-named-pipe`

```
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
enable-named-pipe           # this line
key_buffer = 16M
```

or let mysql listen on a TCP/IP port by commenting out the option skip-networking:

```
# SECURITY CHANGES
# skip-networking           # this line
```

If networking is disabled and named pipes are not enabled then mysqld will useless.

Answer (score 3):

With mysql 8 on windows, if you try to start it from command line with skip-grant-tables you will hit [this error](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90554).
And the solution is adding shared-memory.

```
.\mysqld --skip-grant-tables --shared-memory
```